# How to deploy a DACPAC(Database Project) on Target Database when Service Broker(SB) is enabled and SB is part of AG group

Tags: sql-server-2012, service-broker, dacpac

I have a dacpac which was working fine during deployments and recently we had to enable service broker and include it in AG group for a database. Since this change when we try to deploy the dacpac to database the dacpac is trying to disable the Service Broker before executing any of the changes from dacpac itself and failing to disable the broker as the SB is part of AG group.

does anyone have experienced similar situation and know how to overcome this step during dacpac deployment ?

any suggestions are greatly appreciated.